# Return Url in Paypal Not Working Even is Set Auto Return

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

in my Paypal `sandbox` account on this link

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments
```

I am Setting Auto Return URL Entering as

```
http://prdemos.com/Web/ranch/pay.php
```

and `AUTO RETURN` option (Radio Button) set to `ON` but when i save settings it Shows me message

```
You have successfully saved your preferences.
```

when i process the transaction, and after 10 seconds,the redirected page opens the Paypal sandbox Log in `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/home` Page not mine which i set.

Note: When i go to Setting again the auto return Option is Closed..

did i missing any option? please any one can HELP..!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: @SteveSanders not i left the Project...! and i didn't find any solution..